# Apache CXF forward to JSP page with model

Tags: java, apache, cxf, jax-rs

I use Apache CXF. And I have this controller

```
@GET
@Path("/benchmark")
@Produces("text/html")
public Response getForbiddenBrowserList() {
    MyModel model = generateMyModel();
    //And now I want to do something like:
    return Response.ok( JspView("WEB-INF/pages/benchmark.jsp", model) ).build();
}
```

I cannot find something like "JspView" in Apache CXF. How to return a JSP page in apace CXF and pass "model" to JSP?

Can you provide me an simple example, please? (I found [this documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-redirection.html), but it doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I have one possible solution. It didn't work me before because I forget register jaxrs:provider

**Controller:**

```
@GET
@Path("/benchmark")
@Produces("text/html")
public MyModel getForbiddenBrowserList() {
    MyModel model = generateMyModel();
    //And now I want to do something like:
    return MyModel;
}
```

**jax-rs spring config:**

```
    <jaxrs:server id="notesService" address="/">
    ...
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="dispatchProvider"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>

  <bean id="dispatchProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.RequestDispatcherProvider">
      <property name="classResources">
          <map>
              <entry key="com.acme.MyModel" value="/WEB-INF/pages/model.jsp"/>
          </map>
      </property>
      <property name="beanNames">
          <map>
              <entry key="com.acme.MyModel" value="myModel"/>
          </map>
      </property>
 </bean>
```

**And model.jsp:**

```
<%@ page import="com.acme.MyModel" %>
<%
    MyModel myModel= (MyModel) request.getAttribute("myModel");
%>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        Model: <%= myModel.value %>
    </body>
</html>
```